# Spurt in Close Votes

Tags: discussion, moderators

So I don't know why but suddenly there is a spurt of "Close Vote" revies in my queue. It probably has something to do with the mass editing of posts by @Pheo. What exactly is the community policy for this matter? Because most of the question are pretty highly up-voted like:

[Deducing features from the data-set](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/deducing-the-features-from-the-data-set)

[Computing resources needed for Reinforcement Learning/Machine Imagery](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5981/computing-resources-needed-for-reinforcement-learning-machine-imagery)

I want to know what is the suitable action in few of these example questions. Should the mods do something?

Comment: I have made a total of 0 close votes. Just saying. And if you look at the questions, there are 0 flags towards closing. Odds are it does have something to do with me indirectly, though...

Comment: Could someone give me specs on this: "Chance that the system has detected that standards are changing"

Comment: @Pheo As far as I know, the system does not have any knowledge of site standards. Questions are never pushed into Close Votes without a human thinking it should be closed, but for what it's worth, there are some text heuristics that push things into Low Quality Posts.

Comment: Unless a post is egregious, and clearly off-topic, I try to follow Ben N's lead on closure, since he's been modding here the longest.  But it's rare a day passes when I don't have at least 1 close vote in my queue.  I think, because we're still Beta, and still defining ourselves, the close votes can be taken as dissenting opinions on the scope of this Stack.  It's good for us to get those opinions, but in general, we seem to prefer leniency.  (I personally prefer to try and salvage questions, as opposed to closing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edits don't cause things to head to the close vote queue. Edits on a closed question will sometimes push a question into the *reopen* queue, but never the close vote queue.

So for some reason, someone must have gone through and manually cast close votes/flags, pushing it into the queue.

Votes shouldn't affect the action you take on the post - if it was highly voted but then determined to be off topic, close it. If it's not close-worthy, leave it open. Each question should be judged on its own - if the standing policy on a specific type of question is that it should be closed, review it and pick the appropriate close reason. If you don't, pick Leave Open.

Unless someone is flooding the Close Votes queue with a mass of on topic questions, I don't think that any moderator action is necessary. There's nothing wrong with going through old questions that should be closed (although some would consider it a waste of time).

Comment: Well should i vote for it or against it?

Comment: @DuttaA - I can't give you an answer for every question individually, you have to judge each one by yourself.

Comment: @DuttaA do what you feel is right in terms of voting for closure.  Again, because we're Beta, I think it's in our interest to attempt to salvage as many of them as we can, the most basic, beginner question in particular (i.e. the people who are still so new to Stack, or the field of AI, they don't yet know how to ask questions.  As an analogy, it's taken me quite a while to learn what types of questions are appropriate on SE:Math b/c I'm coming from outside the field.)

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely an uncommon surge in close votes in the queue at present.  (Typically we see serial downvoting, but no so many close vote.)

It's useful information, in the sense of getting user opinions re: what's in scope, but we tend not to actually close unless the question is egregiously off-topic, unsuitable, or unsalvagable.

It's possible it is due to all the edits, bringing buried questions to light...